# Multivariable 1st Derivative Test (system of equations)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to find the critical points for

$f(x,y,z)=2xyz+x^2+y^2+z^2$

by solving the system of equations (setting the x,y,z partial derivatives to 0)

$f_x = 2yz + 2x = 0$

$f_y = 2xy+2y =0$

$f_z = 2xy +2z = 0$

The resulting critical pts are $: (0, 0, 0),(−1, 1, 1),(−1, −1, −1),(1, −1, 1), and (1, −1, 1)$

I am struggling to do find these values. How should this be done?

Comment: corrected******

Comment: Use the symmetry of your system.

Comment: Not sure what that means

Comment: If you set $x \to y, y \to z, z \to x$ in $f_{x}$, you get $f_{y}$. Using a similar approach, you can get $f_{z}$ from $f_{y}$ and $f_{x}$ from $f_{z}$. So, if $(-1, 1, 1)$ is a solution, then so is $(1, -1, 1)$ and $(1, 1, -1)$. The $(0, 0, 0)$ solution should be obvious and the $(-1, -1, -1)$ solution comes from the fact that the product of two negatives is a positive, which is essentially what our 'cyclic' solutions gave us though there we had the product of two positive numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ignore the hessian matrix on the bottom left and the handwriting[image]